# Is there a way to continue only when gobject.idle_add() function terminate?

Tags: python, multithreading, iterator, gtk, pygtk

I want to download images and show the progress with a `gtk.ProgressBar()`.

For this, I used the method recommended in the [PyGTK FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq23.020.htp)  and it works fine :

```
class MainInterface :
  def __init__(self) :
    ...
    thread.start_new_thread(self.getMap, ())

    gtk.gdk.threads_init()
    gtk.gdk.threads_enter()
    gtk.main()
    gtk.gdk.threads_leave()

  def getMap(self) :
    ...
    getImage = self.getImages(new_img_list) # new_img_list is a list of image paths
    gobject.idle_add(getImage.next)

  def getImages(self, img_list) :
    nb_img = len(img_list)
    i = 1.0
    for img in img_list :
        self.progress_interface.progress_bar.set_fraction(i/nb_img)
        gtk.gdk.threads_enter()
        get_maps.download_image(img)    # This function downloads the current image to the disk
        gtk.gdk.threads_leave()
        i += 1.0
        yield True
    self.progress_interface.progress_bar.set_text("Les images sont à jour")
    self.progress_interface.progress_bar.set_fraction(1)
    yield False
```

Now, I have a `ShowMap()` method which create `gtk.Pixbuf` from the images previously downloaded.

So, I want to call this `ShowMap()` function when all the images in `new_img_list` are downloaded (so when `getImage.next()` returns `Falsè`).

How I can to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution : start `ShowMap()` in a new thread in `getImages()`, like this :

```
def getImages(self, img_list) :
    nb_img = len(img_list)
    i = 1.0
    for img in img_list :
        self.progress_interface.set_progress(i, nb_img)
        gtk.gdk.threads_enter()
        get_maps.download_image(img)
        gtk.gdk.threads_leave()
        i += 1.0
        yield True
    self.progress_interface.progress_bar.set_text("Les images sont à jour")
    self.progress_interface.progress_bar.set_fraction(1)
    thread.start_new_thread(self.ShowMap, ()) # Here
    yield False
```

But maybe it have a better solution ?

EDIT :
In fact, this solution doesn't works on Windows (but works on Linux), so it's probably not a proper way to do this.

EDIT 2 :
I finally found the solution by also using a generator function to progressively add rows in the `gtk.IconView` and passing it to `gobject.idle_add()` :

```
def getImages(self, img_list) :
    nb_img = len(img_list)
    i = 1.0
    for img in img_list :
        self.progress_interface.set_progress(i, nb_img)
        gtk.gdk.threads_enter()
        get_maps.download_image(img)
        gtk.gdk.threads_leave()
        i += 1.0
        yield True
    self.progress_interface.progress_bar.set_text("Les images sont à jour")
    self.progress_interface.progress_bar.set_fraction(1)
    map_loading = self.loadMap()
    gobject.idle_add(map_loading.next)
    yield False

def loadMap(self, step=128) :
    i = 1.0
    nb_tiles = len(self.graph) * len(self.graph[0])
    self.grid.iconview.freeze_child_notify()
    for row in self.graph :
        for col in row :
            ...
            self.grid.listStore.append(...)
            self.progress_interface.progressbar_map.set_fraction(i/nb_tiles)
            self.progress_interface.progressbar_map.set_text("Chargement des tuiles en cours ...")
            i += 1.0
            if (i % step) == 0:
                self.grid.iconview.thaw_child_notify()
                yield True
                self.grid.iconview.freeze_child_notify()
    self.grid.iconview.set_model(self.grid.listStore)
    self.grid.iconview.thaw_child_notify()
    yield False
```